# How to resolve runtime error in CNN model related to mismatch input size?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I am trying to run a CNN model on a synthetic dataset consisting of 4000 sample of semi simple random points with 2 features and 1 cluster per class and input data size x is [4000,2] and corresponding labels size is [4000].

I understand that as original input tensor has shape [4000,2] where 4000=total number of samples and 2=number of features and my input to Conv1d layer should be 3d tensor [batch_size,1,2] where 1 is number of input channels and 2 is sequence length but when it runs through dataloader and train function it becomes [1,batch_size,2] and that’s where issue arising.
CNN is defined with its parameters as:

```py
class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, Bias):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1) 
        self.relu = nn.ReLU()                                 
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 20, bias = False)            
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(20, 2, bias = False)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.relu(self.conv1(x))
        x = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1)
        x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x

epochs = 50
alpha = 1e-2
batch_size = 50
criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
model = Net(biases).to(device)
model = train(model.to(device),criterion,x,y,alpha,epochs,batch_size)
```

And I used following train function:

```
def train(model,criterion, x, y, alpha, epochs, batchsize):
    costs = []
    optimizer = torch.optim.SGD(model.parameters(), lr=alpha)    
    trainx, trainy, testx, testy= dataloader(x,y)
    x=trainx.float()
    y=trainy.float()
    data_train = torch.cat((x, y), dim=1)
    data_train_loader = DataLoader(data_train, batch_size=batchsize, shuffle=True)
    model.train()
    j = 0
    for i in range(epochs):
        for index,samples in enumerate(data_train_loader):
            j += 1
            x1 = samples[:,0:2]
            y1 = samples[:,2].long().reshape(-1,1)
            if (j%50 == 0):
                model.eval()
                acc = accuracy(model,testx,testy)
                print(f'Test accuracy is #{acc:.2f} , Iteration number is = {j}')
                model.train()
            cost = criterion(model(x1), y1.squeeze())
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            cost.backward()
            optimizer.step()        
            costs.append(float(cost))
    return model
```

And following is the error I get:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[17], line 7
      5 criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
      6 model = Net(biases).to(device)
----> 7 model=train(model.to(device),criterion,x,y,alpha,epochs,batch_size)
Cell In[15], line 40, in train(model, criterion, x, y, alpha, epochs, batchsize)
     38     print(f'Test accuracy is #{acc:.2f} , Iteration number is = {j}')
     39     model.train()
---> 40 cost = criterion(model(x1), y1.squeeze())
Cell In[16], line 11, in Net.forward(self, x)
     10 def forward(self, x):
---> 11     x = self.relu(self.conv1(x))

RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [1, 1, 1], expected input[1, 50, 2] to have 1 channels, but got 50 channels instead
```

How to solve this input dimension problem or to change the dimension requirement of model input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do

```
x1 = samples[:,0:2] # (batch_size, features)
```

replace with the following to add the channel dimension.
This is similar to unsqueeze, if you have numpy loaded you can replace `None` with `np.newaxis` which is more informative but the same thing.

```
x1 = samples[:, None,0:2]  # (batch_size, 1, features)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you said, the input shape of the Conv1d layer should be 3d tensor [batch_size,1,2] where 1 is number of input channels and 2 is sequence length. However, you are passing a 2D tensor into Conv1d. you need to extend the tensor to be 3d where the second dimension represents the channels by using unsqueeze function. I beileve that in case you don't provide the channel dimension, the tensor is considered to not have a batch dimension. Therefore, it is added automatically. Check the following example:

Input1:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
input = torch.randn( 50, 2) 
convolution_layer = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1) 
feature_map = convolution_layer(input)
```

Output1:

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size [1, 1, 1], expected input[1, 50, 2] to have 1 channels, but got 50 channels instead
```

Input2:

```
import torch
from torch import nn
input = input.unsqueeze(1) 
convolution_layer = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1) 
feature_map = convolution_layer(input)
```

Output2:

```
No errors
```

Modify your model as follow:

```
class Net(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, Bias):
    super(Net, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv1d(1, 1, kernel_size=1, stride=1) 
    self.relu = nn.ReLU()                                 
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(2, 20, bias = False)            
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(20, 2, bias = False)
  def forward(self, x):
    x = self.relu(self.conv1(x.unsqueeze(1)))
    x = x.reshape(x.size(0), -1)
    x = self.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x
```

Or add ".unsqueeze(1)" in the training loop, as follow:

```
cost = criterion(model(x1.unsqueeze(1)), y1.squeeze())
```